# How do I display toast alerts for multiple choices in a drop down?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toast

I have a drop down called "FavoriteFoods." Within this dropdown, I have 4 choices, "Pizza," "Sushi," "Burgers," and "Biryani."

From the "Favorite Foods" drop down, when I select one of the choices, I want a toast pop-up to alert "Great choice!"

How do I achieve this?

```
   <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group">
              <label>Request Type</label>
                <select name="FavoriteFoods" class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;" required>
                   <option value="" disabled selected>Select your favorite food</option>
                    <option value="Pizza">Pizza</option>
                     <option value="Sushi">Sushi</option>
                     <option value="Burgers">Burgers</option>
                     <option value="Biryani">Biryani</option>
               </select>
       </div><!-- /.form-group -->
    </div><!-- /.col -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just bind onchange event for select and toast message.
Please find working example as below

[Jsfiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/rahul25890/jx1f4grL/87/)

```
$(function () {
  $(".select2").change(function(){
   toastr.success("Great Choice");
});

});
```

Comment: Thank you! What if, when they pick "Pizza," it has a different alert? How would I add separate alert messages?

Comment: You can use switch case or business logic inside onclick event, I have updated Jsfiddle for the same.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, I am unable to see the changes in the Jsfiddle.

Comment: i have update Jsfiddle link again. Please refer that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using JQuery you can do it like this

```
$(".select2").change(function(){
     alert(this.val());  // you can use your custom alert options like toastr 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery to select the value from the select box.Then compare it and show the alert.A sample demo :

```js
$( "select[name*='FavoriteFoods']" ).change(function(event){
    console.log($(this).val());

    if($(this).val() == 'Pizza' || $(this).val() == 'Sushi'){
      alert("Great choice ")
    } else{
      alert("Selected item is"+ $(this).val())
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group">
              <label>Request Type</label>
                <select name="FavoriteFoods" class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;" required>
                   <option value="" disabled selected>Select your favorite food</option>
                    <option value="Pizza">Pizza</option>
                     <option value="Sushi">Sushi</option>
                     <option value="Burgers">Burgers</option>
                     <option value="Biryani">Biryani</option>
               </select>
       </div><!-- /.form-group -->
    </div><!-- /.col -->
```